# What is the function of "of" in "of her immortal sisters" and "that of Roy Bhaskar"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, sentence-construction

There are two long sentences here, I quoted from different books.

> If you paint the same face, and set a winged rose or a rose of gold somewhere about her, one's thoughts are of her immortal sisters, Piety and Jealousy, and of her mother, Ancestral Beauty, and of her high kinsmen, the Holy Orders, whose swords make a continual music before her face.

The part of this sentence that confused me is "are of her immortal sisters". What makes me confused in this parts of the sentence is the verb "to be" which is used before "of". So, I'm actually asking if we can remove "are" and replace it just before the "the Holy Orders" as I wrote below:

> "If you paint the same face, and set a winged rose or a rose of gold somewhere about her, one's thoughts of her immortal sisters, Piety and Jealousy, and of her mother, Ancestral Beauty, and of her high kinsmen, **are** the Holy Orders, whose swords make a continual music before her face.

Even if I'm wrong, I think this sentence says that when a painter paints a woman's portrait with a rose or golden rose, it reminds the viewer of some religious thoughts because of the allegoric function of the rose.

> The title of this book echoes that of Roy Bhaskar, A Realist Theory of Science, and this immodest act is homage to an important work that gave impetus to the movement of Critical Realism to which my work contributes.

and here I got confused about "that of Roy Bhaskar". To be clear, I feel like there is something missing between "that" and "of". So, what I should understand is "The title of this book echoes that (title of book) of Roy Bhaskar, A Realist Theory of Science"? Or can we simply get rid of "that" from the sentence, if we can't, why?

Answer (score 1):

This is really two questions, but since they both involve **of**:

Your first passage:

> If you paint the same face, and set a winged rose or a rose of gold somewhere about her, one's thoughts are of her immortal sisters, Piety and Jealousy, and of her mother, Ancestral Beauty, and of her high kinsmen, the Holy Orders, whose swords make a continual music before her face.

Here *one's thoughts* are of three things:

1. her immortal sisters, Piety and Jealousy
2. her mother, Ancestral Beauty
3. her high kinsmen, the Holy Orders

I am not certain whether or not Piety, Jealousy, and Ancestral Beauty are included in those *whose swords make a continual music before her face.* or if that is only her high kinsmen, the Holy Orders.

The author is trying to express the beauty of a woman by saying looking at her invokes thoughts of these [other worldly, fey,](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fey) or [ethereal](https://www.wordnik.com/words/ethereal) beings.

---

Your other passage sounds like an author's foreword to a book, but a quick web search didn't reveal a source:

> The title of this book echoes that of Roy Bhaskar, A Realist Theory of Science, and this immodest act is homage to an important work that gave impetus to the movement of Critical Realism to which my work contributes.

You could get wordy and write something like:

> The title of this book echoes the title of the book by Roy Bhaskar...

However, the original sentence is a higher reading level, and the author sounds rather [pretentious](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pretentious) by comparing his work to that of an important author in the same field, so he probably did his best to sound as educated as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion changes the entire meaning of the sentence. Removing "are" from the second line and inserting it below there, before "Holy Waters" is something else actually.

> If you paint the same face, and set a winged rose or a rose of gold somewhere about her, one's thoughts are of her immortal sisters, Piety and Jealousy, and of her mother, Ancestral Beauty, and of her high kinsmen, the Holy Orders, whose swords make a continual music before her face.

In this sentence, "are" is representing the thoughts related to or surrounding to the lady's painting. The other mentioned entities are in fact the names of the different things associated with *her*.

Whereas, in this sentence,

> If you paint the same face, and set a winged rose or a rose of gold somewhere about her, one's thoughts of her immortal sisters, Piety and Jealousy, and of her mother, Ancestral Beauty, and of her high kinsmen, are the Holy Orders, whose swords make a continual music before her face.

Using "are" before the noun "Holy Waters" is indicating that all the properties/people namely her sisters, her mother and her kinsmen **are thought of as the Holy Orders.** This is completely different than what the original statement mean.

Now as for you title question, *"of"* is representing the girl or lady in the painted picture. In relation to her, people will be remembering her immortal sisters, her mother, and her kinsmen.

> The title of this book echoes that of Roy Bhaskar, A Realist Theory of Science, and this immodest act is homage to an important work that gave impetus to the movement of Critical Realism to which my work contributes.

This sentence means that the book is about a certain someone named Roy Bhaskar, his theory or thesis, and the other related works. *"That of"* is used to refer to the entity of discussion, in this case, the book.

You can also refer to this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61711/whats-the-exact-usage-of-that-of) if you want to see more uses of *that of*.

Comment: `there is no mention of the words "to be" before "of"` but the word in bold in "…her thoughts **are** of…" is an inflected form (am/is/are) of the verb "to be".

Comment: Okay, I understand. I was under the impression that there is actually the words "to be" hence I was searching for it the line.